# WooCommerce - Shipping classes for specific products

Tags: woocommerce

Our customer currently sells artificial grass and has 3 different shipping zones set up depending on where in the UK the order is being shipped.

They’ve now decided to also sell accessories, but they want the shipping to work the following way:

> A flat delivery cost on any purchase of these accessories nationwide
>   will be £10 if the customer is purchasing accessories only (no grass
>   sale). If the customer is purchasing a grass sale and accessories at
>   the same time then there will only be the grass delivery charge to be
>   added as they will be delivered at the same time.

Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try already to achieve what you need? Do you already have an idea? Just asking for a solution is not liked much on SO, especially if you are earning money with a solution

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, I added the following code to my functions.php file in my child theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'specific_products_shipping_methods', 10, 2);
function specific_products_shipping_methods($rates, $package) {
    $terms = array('grass');
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $method_instances_ids = array('flat_rate:9', 'flat_rate:10', 'flat_rate:11');
    $found = false;
    foreach($package['contents'] as $cart_item) {
        if (has_term($terms, $taxonomy, $cart_item['product_id'])) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! $found) return $rates;
    foreach($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
        if (in_array($rate_id, $method_instances_ids)) {
            unset($rates[$rate_id]);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

This hides the accessories shipping options if there is a grass product in the cart.